# androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult policy violation issue

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, google-play-console, policy

My app is getting rejected again and again with the same policy violation without any more details.

As they are saying my this file is causing the issue

"**androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult**"

and but this file is from this library "**implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'**".

Which is required by every other apps. and even my another app which is for doctor is using same libraries as my patient app i've cross compared both the apps and didn't find any difference. as compared to my previous release i've not done any other changes except for some additional API changes. if my app is vulnerable to Intent Redirection.
Then anyone can help me find the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What policy it is violating can you add that here?

Comment: DoctorOnline - Patient, (com.doctoronline.telehealth.patient) (App Bundle:31), violates the Device and Network Abuse policy: &  my app is vulnerable to Intent Redirection https://stackoverflow.com/users/9701793/rahat

Comment: This [article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9267555?hl=en) can help you.

Comment: You got any solution ?

Comment: @MageshPandian https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65931911/notification-from-google-play-malicious-behavior-or-user-data-policy-inten this may help. i've solved this.